# Get the Dynamic text boxes values in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi guys i want to get the Dynamically created text boxes values into an array. Here i am appending two text boxes to a div, my code till now is:

```
 $('<p class = "child" >StopName:<input class="stop" type="text" style="width:120px;" id="p_new" name="stop' + i + '"/>Time: <input type="text" style="width:120px;" id="t_new" name="time' + i + '"/><tr></td> <img src="/Route/images/close.png" id="remove">Remove</p>').appendTo(addDiv);
```

I am trying to get the first text box values as:

```
    $("#btnvalues").click(function () {
    var Stops = [];
    var Values = "";


    $('#divAdd .child input:text').each(function () {


        Values = $("input[name^= 'stop' ]").val();


        // Values += $(this).val() + ",";
        Stops.push(Values);


    });
```

Will this give me all text box values starting with 'stop'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you code `$("input[name^= 'stop' ]").val();` Here you are using attribute starts with selector and you have used `.val()` so it will give you the value of first input text whose name starts with `stop`.

However you have used `.each()` so it will iterate for all input text and populate array with same value.

As you have added class `stop` to first input, You should use it.

```
var Stops = [];
var Values = "";
$('#divAdd .child input:text.stop').each(function () {
    Values = $(this).val();
    Stops.push(Values);
});
```